# append form inside .getJSON to a child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, getjson

Hi i am using getJSON to get information about youtube videos and i am trying to display it in my website.

```
$.each($('section'), function() {
              var video_id = $(this).attr("id");


            $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+video_id+'?v=2&alt=jsonc',function(data,status,xhr){

                 $('.views').append(data.data.viewCount);

                 $('.author').append(data.data.uploader);

                 $('.likes').append(data.data.likeCount);

         }); 

        });
```

The problem I am having is that the data is appended to each and every classes. 
Is there any way i can append the data to this perticular section only.

Comment: It really depends on what particular section you are referring to.  You most likely will have to tweak the selector ( '.views', '.author', '.likes' ) to include some more granularity.  If you ahve the HTML you are dealing with, post it.

Comment: i am using .each() to get id from each and every video(which is in section tag). So i would love to see data displayed on the video with that particular id

Comment: You can call `.each()` directly on selections. It is much cleaner. E.g. `$("section").each(...);`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to descend from for the `section` DOM element, to avoid selecting all the elements of a class in the DOM.

```
$.each($('section'), function() {
    var video_elem = $(this);
    var video_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+video_id+'?v=2&alt=jsonc',function(data,status,xhr){
        video_elem.find('.views').append(data.data.viewCount);
        video_elem.find('.author').append(data.data.uploader);
        video_elem.find('.likes').append(data.data.likeCount);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: ```video_id``` is a string, not a DOM element.